# Ubuntu 20.04 - no menu bar in LibreOffice

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, menu, gnome-flashback

In Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME flashback, there is no menu bar in LibreOffice (the one with File, View etc.). I read somewhere on the Net that the issue is related to libreoffice-gtk3 package, and uninstalling it brings the menu back. I tried it - it indeed brings the menu back, but the menu is very ugly, as it has a "raw" X application look, completely unrelated to the currently set GNOME theme.
How to bring the menus back in LO while keeping the system theme?

It looks that Ubuntu is getting worse with every release. I started with Ubuntu 10.04 where everything worked just perfectly "out of the box". With each new release I install, there is more and more trivial things that are not working and require much effort to fix.

EDIT: Just found another LibreOffice issue - help does not work. How many more will there be? Starting to think about reverting to Ubuntu 18.04...

Comment: I don't want to remove GNOME.

Comment: Do you have `indicator-appmenu` installed? `apt-cache policy indicator-appmenu`

Comment: Yes, it's installed

Comment: I filed a bug for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1883423 as similar bug seems to be present on KDE: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1863282

Comment: @raj Post somewhere output of `dconf dump /org/gnome/gnome-panel/`.

Comment: Here it is, after my recent changes to the panel: http://rafa.eu.org/share/public/panel.conf.txt

Comment: @akshat-zala why did you remove `gnome-flashback` tag? That was valid tag... And how this post is related to software installation?

Comment: @muktupavels I reverted the tags to previous

Comment: "I started with Ubuntu 10.04 where everything worked just perfectly..." -- this is so true.

Comment: Try to reset a Panel. In my case, that helped.

Comment: I can see all that problems to a small laptop I have on the other hand on my main laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 all problems are simply fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing completely the indicator-appmenu applet from the panel solved the issue! The menu is back where it should be.

The question is, was the applet in the panel from the beginning (in that case it's actually a bug, it shouldn't be there) or I accidentally put it there while configuring the panel...

Comment: How to remove it from panel. Where is the panel?   There is no panel in setting. I just apt-get autoremove indicator-appmenu, and it does not work.

Comment: Note that this question applies to GNOME Flashback desktop. We were talking all the time about the top panel on the desktop. You can add and remove applets from the panel. I did not remove the indicator-appmenu package, I only removed the applet from the panel, so that it is not active.

Comment: @raj How do you remove this applet? I can't really see it. I removed all the applets on the top panel, except for the "Main Menu" one, but I still cannot see the LibreOffice menu.

Comment: It can be hard to remove it if you don't see it. Use `dconf-editor` (install it if you don't have it), go to `/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/` and check what applets do you have in your panel. If you have `indicator-appmenu` key there, you can remove it by removing all it's subkeys, and also you need to go a level up (to `/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout`) and remove 'indicator-appmenu' from the list of values in `object-id-list`. However, if the applet is not there, you probably have another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `bamfdaemon`. It should be started with session but you can start it manually after installing with `systemctl --user start bamfdaemon.service`.

I think you might have appmenu applet on panel that loads `indicator-appmenu`... But it is empty because of missing dependency.

Comment: Oh no! :) This puts the application menu on top of my GNOME panel, overwriting what's already there, and not where it should be, in application window under the title bar! It's usable, but looks strange - look at the screenshot: http://rafa.eu.org/share/public/bamfdaemon.png . I also can't access the main panel menu this way.

Comment: I managed to clean the panel up a bit: http://rafa.eu.org/share/public/bamfdaemon2.png . This is acceptable as a workaround, until the bug is properly fixed. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want appmenu in panel then remove applet. :) Alt + Right click -> Remove from panel.

Comment: Yes, someone else already wrote me that :) The question is only, was the applet there by default or I accidentally put it there...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround until the cause of this issue is resolved, try the snap version of LibreOffice. As this is configured in its own container, it will not be affected by potential issues with the Gnome flashback configuration.

The snap version can be installed along the regular version. To avoid confusion, you may prefer removing the current installation:

```
sudo apt autoremove libreoffice
```

To install the SNAP version of libreoffice,

```
sudo snap install libreoffice
```

Comment: Does not work. I installed the "snap" with LibreOffice 7.x now, and I can't see the menu either. This is a blocker.

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu mate 20.04 and i had all the above problems after adding an applet at the top bar of the system.

The solution is really easy: try to remove strange applets from the top bar - I don't even remember mine although I searched for it!

After removing it all menus are back!